# Weighted Average Entry/Exit Cost

Tags: excel, finance, weighted-average

Hello I have a question regarding some data that I have extracted into Excel. In particular the Market Depth of a Aluminium.  I am trying to calculate what the average entry/exit cost would be for a set number of contracts.

I would be very appreciative of any help one could provide.

**Example:**
I have set the amount to 20. How could i calculate the weighted average entry price? (Assuming we lift the offer (`"Buy"`) and Hit the Bid (`"Sell"`)

I have pasted the format of my data below. I have been using this to limit thew Vol (`"Volume"`) to be the amount i entered where `"R4=20 ATM"`.

```vb
 =MIN(SUM($G$3:$G$12),$R$4)
```

[image: See My Data Format Here!]

Comment: Column G refers to?

Comment: My Bad, So Column G is looking at the ASK Volume   R4 references the Amount I want to sell. In this example 20. 

Column D would therefore be the Bid Volume